# error shown in resove com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

[click here to check exact error which i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLFfV.png)

```
 buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my build.gradel in project level
you can check the image link for the exact error,which will reflect my problem..
[every thing which is needed for upgradation is already over yyou can check this by clicking here i have provided one screenshot for  that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvXyV.png)

i am scratching my mind from the past few days.please help me

Comment: When posting to Stack Overflow, please copy the text of code and errors into the question itself rather than using screenshots.  This makes it much easier to read and search.

Comment: kindly reply to the question.i will take care of that

Comment: @PeterHaddad ofcourse,but it didn't work for me..anything else which you wanna add

Answer (score 1):

The error is (according to the image):

> Failed to resolve:com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3

To solve that use version `16.0.1` for `firebase-database` since it is the latest one.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

You can check [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) for the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the libraries this way

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

You have to change the instruction '**compile**' to '**implementation**'